# PreviousPageModel is null

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have a Xamarin.Forms application with freshmvvm framework. According to the documentation, I can use PreviousPageModel property of FreshBasePageModel base class to access data of the PageModel I navigated from. I navigate like this:

```
    public FirstPageModel()
    {
        _validator = new CalculatorValidator();
        CalculateCommand = new Command(execute: () => 
        {
            ValidationResult = _validator.Validate(this);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ValidationResult));

            if (ValidationResult.IsValid)
            {
                CoreMethods.PushPageModel<SecondPageModel>();
            }
        });
    }
```

The navigation happens, but in the SecondPageModel constructor the PreviousPageModel is null:

```
    public SecondPageModel()
    {
        _previousModel = (FirstPageModel)PreviousPageModel;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I also tried:

```
    public FirstPageModel()
    {
        _validator = new CalculatorValidator();
        CalculateCommand = new Command(Calculate);
    }

    private void Calculate()
    {
        ValidationResult = _validator.Validate(this);
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ValidationResult));

        if(ValidationResult.IsValid)
        {
            CoreMethods.PushPageModel<SecondPageModel>(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/365262/#Comment_365262

The PreviousPageModel is null because it hasn't been set in the constructor. Place your code in the ViewIsAppearing lifecycle event, then you will get the correct previous model:

```
protected override void ViewIsAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.ViewIsAppearing(sender, e);

    _previousModel = (FirstPageModel)PreviousPageModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that until this point in time, In your PageModel lifecycle the `PreviousPageModel`property this not assigned a value.

Now I am sure that this property is available by the time the Init lifecycle method is called i.e.

```
public override void Init(object initData)
{
  _previousModel = (FirstPageModel)PreviousPageModel;
}
```

But if you do not want to do this and want it to be strictly in your constructor what you can do is call the base implementation and hope that our friend micheal has assigned this property there:

Something like below:

```
public SecondPageModel() : base()
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try it in Init(), and PreviousPageModel is still null.

Comment: Is it? What version of fresh do you have bro?

Comment: The very fresh one. BTW, when I move to FirstPage from the Menu page using the same code, PreviousPageModel is populated correctly. I don't understand what the difference is, and where I should look for a bug...

Comment: I see your problem now!!

Comment: Could you please clarify what is wrong and what you suggest? BTW, I added something to my initial question.

Comment: The constructor of `FirstPageModel` is directly calling the `SecondPageModel` and there is not enough time for the `PreviousPageModel` to be set can you move this code a little further in your lifecycle?

Comment: Move it to the end of the init method like this : `public override async void Init(object initData)
{ if(ValidationResult.IsValid)
        {
            await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<SecondPageModel>(this);
        }}`

Comment: No, the CalculateCommand is executed on pressing a button to which it is assigned. The code in the constructor only defines what that Command should do when called. But I still tried to move it to Init(), with no success.

Comment: somehow I completely missed that sorry its embarrassing